# $\{y_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge to $y\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with respect to box topology

Tags: general-topology

For each $m\in \mathbb{N}$, define $$y_m(j)= y(j), \;\;\;\;\mbox{if $\;\;$ $j\leq m$,}$$ and $$y_m(j)=0, \;\;\;\; \mbox{if $\;\;$ j>m}.$$

How will I show  that $\{y_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ does not converge to $y\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $y(j)\neq 0$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ when endowed in box topology.

In particular, what open box in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ contains $y$ but not $y_m$?

Please help me with this problem in the book. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that open sets in ${\large{\Box}}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$ are of the form $${\textstyle \prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}}} U_j$$ where each $U_j$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ (and there is no requirement that any of these are the full real line).

- For $y \in \prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} U_j$ we must have that $y(j) \in U_j$ for all $j$.
- For $y_m \notin \prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} U_j$ we just need $y_m (j) \notin U_j$ for *some* $j$; $j = m+1$ might be a good choice.

(So, for example, can you think of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $y(2)$ but not $y_1(2)$?)

Comment: @PeachyChiu: If you are trying to take $U_m = ( y(m-1) , y(m) )$, note that $y(m) \notin U_m$.  (Also, this only makes sense if $y(m-1) < y(m)$, which we do not know.  All we do know is that $y(j) \neq 0$ for all $j$.)  I think you might be _thinking too hard about this_. There is a simple solution which will probably seem like cheating once you come up with it.

Comment: @PeachyChiu: Note that $y(2) \neq 0$ by assumption, and $y_1(2) = 0$ by definition.  If $y(2) > 0$ then $( 0 , + \infty )$ is an open set containing $y(2)$ but not $y_1(2)$.  If $y(2) < 0$, then... _(you can fill in the blank)_.

Comment: @PeachyChiu: You're welcome! _(And doesn't that seem like cheating?_)

Comment: @PeachyChiu: Change the "$y_{j+1}(j)$" to "$y_j(j+1)$" and you're fine (modulo perhaps adding an explanatory sentence or two).

Comment: @PeachyChiu: Yeah, if you want to. If you really want to have meaningful subscripts you can just say "let $U_j = ( - \infty , 0 ) \cup ( 0 , +\infty )$ for each $j$." It might be somewhat easier for someone else to read.  (Again, you have the switch the subscript and the index in the parethesis.)